# Prove that p divides to algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, positive-characteristic

I need help in the following exercise of a qualifying exam:

Let $A$ be a matrix of size $m$ by $m$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $\operatorname{trace}\left(A^n\right)=0$ for all $n$. If $\lambda$ is a nonzero eigenvalue of $A$, prove that the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is divisible by $p$.

Thank you by some hints.

Comment: This is very nice! Let $f = \det\left(I_m - XA\right) \in \mathbb{F}_p\left[X\right]$ (this is a variation on the characteristic polynomial of $A$). You need to show that $f$ is a $p$-th power of a polynomial. Equivalently, all coefficients of $f$ before $x^k$ with $p \nmid k$ are zero. Equivalently, the derivative $f^\prime$ of $f$ is zero. Equivalently, $Xf^\prime / f = 0$ (in the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{F}_p\left[\left[X\right]\right]$. But $Xf^\prime / f = - \sum_{k \geq 1} \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^k\right) X^k$ (or something close).

Comment: PS: Sorry for the brevity and the lack of double checking (whoever makes this into a real answer gets my +1 for sure). Also, I assumed that "for all $n$" means "for all $n \geq 0$". Thus, the word "nonzero" is useless. If you mean "for all $n \geq 1$" instead, then "nonzero" becomes important, but a similar argument to the one given above should go through.

Comment: Yes, is for all $n$ integer with $n\geq1$, the case $n=0$ is absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darij's argument is undoubtedly much smarter (I don't understand it), but the following simple approach works too. In the algebraic closure, we have the Jordan normal form available, so if $m_j$ denotes the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_j$, then your assumption now says that $\sum m_j \lambda_j^n=0$ for all $n\ge 1$, or, equivalently, $\sum m_jp(\lambda_j)=0$ for all polynomials with $p(0)=0$. We can now take $p=\lambda\prod_{k\not= j} (\lambda-\lambda_k)$ to see that $m_j\equiv 0\mod p$ if $\lambda_j\not= 0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you by your answer is very good, but I not know as $\sum m_j\lambda_j\prod_{k\neq j}(\lambda_j-\lambda_k)=0$ implies that $m_j\equiv 0$ mod $p$.

Comment: Maybe each term in the sum is zero, but I not can prove it.

Comment: @AlexCg. - fix $j$, and $p$ as above. Then $p(\lambda_k)=0$ iff $k\not=j$, so $\sum m_k p(\lambda_k) = 0$ reduces to $m_j p(\lambda_j) = 0$, and $m_j=0$ if $\lambda_j \not = 0$. Last night I had a similar idea, but not as elegant as Christian's (+1): omit $\lambda_0 = 0$ from $\sum_{j=1}^s m_j \lambda_j^n =0$, form a (square matrix) Vandermonde style of equation. The determinant is non-zero, so the matrix is invertible, and the $(m_1,\cdots, m_s)=0$

Comment: (cont) By' Vandermonde style' I mean of the form $(\lambda_j^n)$, $n,\ j$ running from $1$ to $s$.

Comment: Sorry Peter, but you answer is not clearly, because, for example if exists only three eigenvalues ($\lambda_1 $, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$), I have that the expresion $\sum m_jp(\lambda_j)=0$ implies that                                                                     $$m_1\lambda_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\lambda_1-\lambda_3)+m_2\lambda_2(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)(\lambda_2-\lambda_3)+m_3\lambda_3(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)(\lambda_3-\lambda_2)=0,$$                                                                           then my problem is, as this implies that $m_j=0$ mod $p$, $j=1,2,3$.

Comment: Peter, however You idea using the form to Vandermonde style is very good. Thank you soo Much

Comment: @AlexCg. Peter's (first) comment explains what I had in mind. The polynomial $p$ gives you that $m_j$ is a multiple of the characteristic, and then you need to consider such a $p$ for each $j$ (so $p$ depends on $j$).

Comment: @AlexCg. I'm in the odd  position of saying how much nicer Christian's answer is than mine... To take your example situation, say we have $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ as the distinct eigen-values, non-zero for simiplicity, with multiplicity $m_k$. We want to show $m_1$ is zero in $\overline {\mathbb F}_p$.
Write $$p_1(\lambda ) = \lambda (\lambda -\lambda_2) (\lambda -\lambda_3).$$
Then  
$$ m_1p_1(\lambda_1) +m_2p_1(\lambda_2) + m_3p_1(\lambda_3) =0.$$
As $p_1(\lambda_2)=p_1(\lambda_3)=0, $ and $p_1(\lambda_1)\not=0$, we conclude $m_1 = 0$ - etc....

Comment: Thank you,  Christian Remling and Peter by this helps, now I have it pretty clear.  :)